# can't run vpython program("dll load failed" error)?

Tags: python

so I recently tried to download vpython 5.74(5.74?) for python 3.2.5, and then run one of the example programs, but this following code is producing an error

```
from visual import *

floor = box(length=4, height=0.5, width=4, color=color.blue)

ball = sphere(pos=(0,4,0), color=color.red)
ball.velocity = vector(0,-1,0)

dt = 0.01
while 1:
    rate(100)
    ball.pos = ball.pos + ball.velocity*dt
    if ball.y < 1:
        ball.velocity.y = -ball.velocity.y
    else:
        ball.velocity.y = ball.velocity.y - 9.8*dt​
```

the error on the shell where it ran says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\visual\examples\bounce.py", line 1
    from visual import *
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\visual\__init__.py", line 1
    from .visual_all import *
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\visual\visual_all.py", line 1
    from vis import version
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\vis\__init__.py", line 3
    from .cvisual import (vector, dot, mag, mag2, norm, cross, rotate,
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
>>> ​
```

any help with how this error occurred?

Comment: That "DLL load failed" error _often_ (but not always) means that you've installed a 64-bit extension module with a 32-bit Python, or vice-versa.

Comment: Is there a reason you're still using Python 3.2?

Comment: it  just is the most recent one that vpython has caught up to, as far as I know and my computer science teacher said.

Comment: Well, on [Christoph Gohlke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#vpython) there are packages for 3.3 and 3.4—and he's dropped the packages for 3.2. So it sounds like your teacher is out of date, and you may want to tell him that.

Answer (score 0):

This often (not always, but it's the most common reason for this problem) means that you've installed a 64-bit extension module, then tried to use it with a 32-bit Python, or vice-versa.<sup>*</sup>

From your comments, I'm pretty sure you downloaded a 32-bit `vpython`, and tried to use it with a 64-bit Python.

---

From looking at the [`vpython` download page](http://vpython.org/contents/download_windows.html#python3), they supply a 32-bit installer for Python 3.2 only, and suggest using [Christoph Gohlke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#vpython) for 64-bit versions. However, Gohlke has dropped support for 3.2 and only has 3.3 and 3.4 since the last time they edited that page.

If `vpython` were on PyPI and had official wheels, and you had up-to-date versions of `pip` and `wheel` (which come with Python 3.4 out of the box, but for 3.2 you have to install them), you could just `pip install vpython` and it would download the right versions, and all of the prerequisites. Unfortunately, they don't appear to be on PyPI, and the packages on their site and Gohlke's seem to be the only way to install `vpython` without building it from source.

So, your choices appear to be:

- Upgrade to 64-bit Python 3.4 and install the new wheels from Gohlke's site. (In this case you'll want the ones labeled `cp34-none-win_amd64.whl`. Follow the instructions at the top of the page to install.)
- Switch to 32-bit Python 3.2 and install the old package from the `vpython` site (the one you already downloaded).
- Build it yourself for your 64-bit Python 3.2.
- Search for an old mirrored copy of Gohlke's 64-bit Python 3.2 version somewhere.

Meanwhile, if your teacher is telling students to use Python 3.2 because it's the latest one that can use `vpython`, you may want to point him to the updated information. He may have a preference for which of the choices he wants you to use. (Or he may have the old 64-bit 3.2 installer lying around.)

---

<sub>* Note that you can run a 32-bit Python on 64-bit Windows, but not the other way around. There are some good reasons to prefer a 64-bit Python—e.g., if your machine has 16GB of RAM, a 64-bit Python can keep nearly 16GB of data in memory, while a 32-bit Python can only keep 2-3GB—but given a choice between hypothetical advantages that may never affect you vs. having the specific version of the specific package that you need, 32-bit may win.</sub>

Comment: I went with one from the vpython website, that did not have an explicit reference of it being 64 or 32-bit

Comment: @NatalieKalos: Looking at [that site](http://vpython.org/contents/download_windows.html#python3), it says "download and install the 32-bit Python-3.2.2 from python.org". And then there's a note that says to go to Gohlke's site if you want a 64-bit version. So I'm pretty sure it's a 32-bit version.

Comment: @NatalieKalos: You can run 32-bit Python on 64-bit Windows. There are advantages to using 64-bit Python, but if it's a choice between "better for a few things that may never be relevant to me" vs. "has a pre-built package that I need", I think the latter is a better choice. Still, I personally would go with 64-bit Python 3.4.